# Можно ли как-нибудь указать приоритеты на использование ОЗУ и файла подкачки?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby-on-rails, ram, swap

Имеется Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 x64 с 512 Mb на борту.

Параллельно запущенному Rails проекту порой запускаются tasks, которым нужна дополнительная ОЗУ. Для этого было решено применить SWAP.

И все вроде бы нормально, но сайт иногда (когда судя по всему его блоки из ОЗУ перемещаются на диск) слегка начинает "думать", а иногда работает быстро. Хотя в обоих случаях висела task.

Можно ли как-нибудь расставить приоритеты, мол, чтобы Rails проект всегда лежал в родной ОЗУ, а также выходил в SWAP, если ему это необходимо, но Rails tasks всегда лежали в SWAP?

Все это работает от одного пользователя. Задачи запускаются CRON по расписанию.

Это вообще возможно реализовать без особого геморроя?

Comment: Любое приложение не может выполнятся с свопа, а только с озу. Также, Ваши таски не знают, когда придет обычный запрос от пользователя, поэтому выполняются тогда, когда им приходит время. Поэтому, самое простое решение - просто добавить чуточку памяти или понять, почему таскам нужно много памяти. Может там можно оптимизировать.

Comment: Можно. [Займётесь переводом на русский язык?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/578137/2076787)

Comment: @D-side спасибо. Да, прочитать на английском смогу.

Comment: Я предлагаю ещё и написать сюда ответ на русском языке, как только разберётесь.

Comment: @D-side без проблем. Как только, так сразу.